# json_decode in php problem with "-" character in string

Tags: php, json, string, parsing, decode

I have a problem with parsing data in json exposed with strings that contain the character "-", for example "foo-opened". All strings containing the value "-" in the php file return value 0 or error.

**FILE JSON:**

```
{
  "overview": [
    {
      "foo": {
        "foo-opened": 0,
        "foo-total": 110,
        "foo-closed": 110
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

**FILE PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$url = "data.json";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$obj=json_decode($contents);
$FooTotal = $obj->overview[0]->foo->foo-opened;
$FooOpen = $obj->overview[0]->foo->foo-total;
$FooClosed = $obj->overview[0]->foo->foo-closed;                          
echo "</p><p>Foo total:" . $FooTotal . "</p><p>Foo open:" . $FooOpen . "</p><p>Foo closed:" . $FooClosed . "</p></p>";
 ?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: sorry, the ',' because is an extract of a json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the prop via `$obj->overview[0]->foo->{'foo-total'}`

Comment: It works with your solution! Thank you @Robbie-Averill for your help!